# How do I change the default configurations for the node options?

Tags: nodes

I want to change some default configurations for the node options; for example, the authoring information has 'Authored by' field which is defaulting to auto-complete authors. I want to change this to a drop down instead.

Is there a module that can do this? I learned that editing a module is not advisable, and I cannot find modules that can override default configurations anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately in that case, I guess that you should do your [own module](http://drupal.org/node/231276) and use [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6)

Answer (score 1):

Editing a module is not advisable; every time you update the module to resolve issues that have been fixed in the module by other users or from the maintainers, you would lost your customizations. If the change can be useful for somebody else, and not just for you, you can propose a patch that could be accepted, and implemented by the module maintainer.

If the change is not interesting for anybody else, or the change aims to resolve an issue that you only have, then you can create your own custom module that alters the form created by another module.
In Drupal almost everything implemented by a module can be altered: You can alter the theme function defined from another module, or you can alter the form implemented by another module, in the same way you can change the tokens implemented by another module (Drupal 7), or you can alter the file where some hook implementations are looked in (still in Drupal 7).

In this case, you can alter the form using hook_form_alter().

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (isset($form['type']) && isset($form['#node']) && $form['type']['#value'] . '_node_form' == $form_id) {

    if (isset($form['author']['name'])) {
      $form['author']['name']['#type'] = 'select';
      $form['author']['name']['#multiple'] = TRUE;

      // This is not strictly necessary, as the autocomplete is not used with the field
      // we are using.
      unset($form['author']['name']['#autocomplete_path']); 

      $form['author']['name']['#options'] = mymodule_build_name_options();
      $form['author']['name']['#default_value'] = $node->name ? $node->name : t('-none-');
      $form['author']['name']['#description'] = t('Select %option for %anonymous.', array('%option' => t('-none-'), '%anonymous' => variable_get('anonymous', t('Anonymous')))),
    );
  }
}
```

`mymodule_build_name_options()` should return the list of the available usernames in an array, such as `array("username 1", "username 2", // …)`.

"mymodule" is the short name of the module you create.

Comment: Yes, I already had an existing custom module just to handle any other extra customizations. I was just wanting to make sure there are really no other modules that can do this before I start to create it. I was even hoping there are no modules so I can learn more with Drupal. The thing is if I have missing functionalities, it turned out there are already existing modules that can achieve the same. So why reinvent the wheel? But in this case, and as far as your answers are concerned, there are none. So I used the form_alter to alter the node form and viola! Thank you all for helping!